# MAC OS's Numbers cant read month of xls generated using Apache POI (3.10.1)

Tags: java, macos, date, apache-poi, xls

Using apache poi library we are generating a report in xls format.
The report column containing date is formatted as `dd.MMM.yyyy` in java code.

This report displays the date cells fine on Windows machine with software MS Office 2013, 2010 & Apache Open Office.The dates are also visible in Mac OS when viewed in Apache Open Office, Libre Office.

But the default software of Mac for excel i.e. 'Numbers' fails to display the month part.

The date is displayed as `01.MMM.2014` in Numbers. I googled about this issue but couldn't get much info.

Can you please throw some light as part I might be missing? Or if you have faced this issue, what solution did you implement.

Thanks,

Hanumant

Comment: Did you make sure you were using the latest version of Apache POI to generate the excel file with?

Comment: Yes @Gagravarr, we are using the latest stable build from Apache poi v 3.10.1

Comment: What happens if you re-save the document in Excel and then try to open it in Numbers, or even create manually a new file with such formatting? Does it work then? This is to rule out it's a general problem with Numbers, and not some quirk with Apache POI.

Comment: Can you try with 3.11 beta 2 / recent nightly build / wait for about Monday then try 3.11 beta 3?

Comment: @cello the problem is only with the xls files generated with apache poi. When you change the file content and again open in numbers the date is visible. but not without editing the date content.